# What is the solution of localization of css and js in the Angular to no need to the Internet to work properly

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want to replace the following line code with local approach(independence of the internet) in the Angular.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What is the best approach(with code)?

Full html file is as following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular10</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed the in angular.json as follows:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
      "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

and download the required files, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Copy the content of https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js and put it one file and link it either in angular.json or import it in your custom css file

Comment: What do you mean of saying put in one file?

Comment: Create file with name"popper.min.js". Follow this https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular

Comment: The problem is solved except <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>, the click button doesn;t work normally.

Comment: Can you please put the code in stackblitz and share the link

Comment: https://github.com/ArtOfEngineer/PythonDjangoAngular10